# Image Resources not showing

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

I have created a android project in Visual Studio.I have a few images in the the Drawable folder. These images show in the Resource designer as well. But when I try to access these images the Project Resource explorer does not show them. Also if I try to use them programatically they don't show up.

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you programming in c# for an Android application? You have the tag c#.

Answer (score 0):

to get resource from drawable folder use this line

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_resource_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "Build Action" on the specific file is "AndroidResource".

Find the resource file in the file explorer, right-click on it, and select the "Build Action" menu item.

It is all very well to have the file in the right file directory location in the operating system, but the Android compiler needs to know what to do with it as well.